# Yocto: Create a directory after mount

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a Yocto bitbake recipe in my layer - `base-files_%.bbappend`. It creates mount points:

```
do_install_append() {
    mknod -m 622 ${D}/dev/console c 5 1
    install -m 0755 -d ${D}/boot/EFI
    install -m 0755 -d ${D}/data
}
```

The `/data/` directory is later mounted to the internal SD card.

I would like to create a directory `${D}/data/test`. What is the best way to do it? I've added a line `install -m 0755 -d ${D}/data/test` to this function but it didn't do it.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ship those installed files by adding to your recipe:

`FILES_${PN} += "/data/test"`

Another solution is to add in your image recipe:

```
create_dirs() {
    mkdir -p ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/data/test
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "create_dirs ; "
```

Comment: `/data/test` is a directory, not a file. I want to create it to have a ready place to put files into during system run. I've tried `FILES_${PN} += "/data/test"` -
 didn't help. Sorry, where is that "image recipe" you've mentioned?

Comment: @ilya1725 each time you perform bitbake to build an image you are actually bitbaking an image recipe(core-image-minimal). Search for it, and then you can either modify it(not recomended) or inheriting your own image recipe adding the suggestions by Nayfe

Comment: @urnenfeld we have our own recipe that does other things and adds to `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`. But it doesn't work on this particular directory, which is mounted a bit later.

Comment: Ok, i missread the question, if /data is mounted, one solution is to create a small service (systemd or sysvinit) that will create /data/test after fstab mount.

Answer (score 0):

In your do_install function

```
do_install(){
    mkdir -d ${D}/data/test
}
```

-d option creates the dir in your rootfs, and if you want to copy files, use below command in do_install function.

```
install -m 0777 ${s}/your files ${D}/data/test
```

The QA packaging process verification should be informed :

```
FILES_${PN} += "/data/test"
```